# How to get mp3 file from resources in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to get URI of `default.mp3` from `resources` and play that file in `System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer`
I included the mp3 file in resources folder as `Content` and `copy always` but I dont know how to play get the URI. I am currently doing this but its not working

```
 uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/default1.mp3");   // This is not working neither showing and error
 var player = new MediaPlayer();
 //MessageBox.Show(uri.ToString());
 player.Open(uri);
 player.Play();
```

Comment: Tried but no luck still not getting any error neither mp3 file is playing

Answer (score 1):

You can not apply file from resource to MediaPlayer in .Net. The music file should be placed in separatly file and Uri created with phisical file path.

Please, see the message details in MediaPlayer.MediaError event.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the 'Build Action' to 'Resource' in order to make the resource accessible through WPF.

You can change this in the properties pane of the file:

[image]

I got it working with these steps:

1. Create resource file in `Resources\default.mp3`;
2. Add resource file to project. Set Build Action to Resource;
3. Use this code:

   ```
   Uri uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WpfApplication1;component/Resources/default.mp3");
   ```

Comment: Try to rebuild your project. Often these changes aren't picked up otherwise.

Comment: Still not working :(   
In windows form I used to get file with this `Properties.Resources.FileName`

Comment: Try this as URI: `pack://application:,,,/The.Full.Assembly.Name;component/Resources/file.mp3`.

Comment: Not working my Assembly name has space in it `Audio Play` so I tried this `pack://application:,,,/Audio Play;component/Resources/default1.mp3` but this is not working either

Comment: What is the namespace of your project? Try that.

Comment: Namespace is Audio_Play tried and not working. My mp3 file is in `Resources` folder `Resources\default.mp3`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64113/discussion-between-uzair-ali-and-patrick-hofman).

Comment: Not working I tried to build new project but still not working. Maybe the problem is on my side. I have create `Resources` folder manually and then drag and drop default.mp3 file in it   
     
`MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
 Uri uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WpfApplication1;component/Resources/default.mp3");
 player = new MediaPlayer();
 MessageBox.Show(uri.IsFile.ToString());
 player.Open(uri);
 player.Play();`

Comment: yes its working when I write this `c:/users/uzair/desktop/default.mp3` in uri

Comment: Did you follow the steps exactly?

Comment: Yes I did but no luck what I tried   
(1) create new WPF project named WpfApplication1   
(2) Create a new folder under project named `Resources`   
(3) Drag and drop the `default.mp3` file from desktop into `Resources` folder   
(4) change the mp3 file's build action to `Resource` and `Copy Always`   
(5) use this code 
`MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(); Uri uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WpfApplication1;component/Resources/default.mp3"); player = new MediaPlayer(); MessageBox.Show(uri.IsFile.ToString()); player.Open(uri); player.Play();`

Comment: Don't set `Copy Always`. Set it to `None`.

Comment: Not working. Can you give me the working project of your's `WpfApplication1` at `@uzairali001@gmail.com` Cause I am tired now

Comment: Sure. Will do when I am back at my pc.